# Semicolon and nested if expressions in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Well, I have problems in using `semicolon (single and double)` and `nested if else` in OCaml.

For example

---

```
let union u p q = 
  let rec unionfy id_ary i =
    if i < Array.length id_ary then begin 
      if id_ary.(i) = p then begin 
        id_ary.(i) <- id_ary.(q);
        print_array id_ary 0;
      end
      unionfy id_ary (i + 1);
    end 
    else print_string "end of union";
  in
  unionfy u.id_ary 0;;
```

---

The compiler said `line 18, characters 29-95:
Error: This expression is not a function; it cannot be applied`

The line which has problem is `if id_ary.(i) = p then begin`, but I don't see why.

---

Also, can anyone tell me more about `semicolon` thing and `nested if else`?

here are some questions in my mind:

1. When do I use `single semicolon`? If I use it for more than one expressions, will I have to add a `double semicolon` after the last expression?
2. Can I use multiple `begin end` inside `nested if`?
3. It seems I don't need to add `else` if the result is `unit and do nothing`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `end`. The entire `if` expression should return `unit` in this case, so you need a semi-colon at the end of the expression. The other `end` doesn't need it since the `if` expression is continuing with the `else` clause. Below, I've removed the unnecessary semi-colons and added the remaining one,

```
let union u p q = 
  let rec unionfy id_ary i =
    if i < Array.length id_ary then begin 
      if id_ary.(i) = p then begin 
        id_ary.(i) <- id_ary.(q);
        print_array id_ary 0
      end;
      unionfy id_ary (i + 1)
    end 
    else print_string "end of union"
  in
  unionfy u.id_ary 0;;
```

*EDIT:* The 'rule' is really the definition of the semi-colon in OCaml. It separates sequential expressions that return `unit`. The content between `begin ... end` is a singular expression. The entire `if` expression is also an expression, but made up of multiple expressions. So the two statements contained in the first `if` statement are,

```
  if id_ary.(i) = p then begin ... end;
  unionfy id_ary (i + 1)
```

Comment: Why we don't need the `;` behind 'print_array id_ary 0`, but we need one for `unionfy id_ary (i + 1);`?

Comment: Could you please extend your answer to describe the general rule of all those?

Comment: Ok, roughly I understand now. `;` is used only when you want to adjacent more than one expressions. In your code or mine, the most inside `if begin end` is actually an expression and together with `unionfy id_ary (i+1)`, they are two adjacent expressions which reside inside the first `if begin end`.Am I right?

Comment: because the print_array is returning `unit` and the expression between `begin ... end` should have type `unit`. The semi-colon is syntactical sugar for `let () = ... in`. So the `;` is necessary to separate the `if` expression and the `unionfy` expression.

Comment: could you please review my another code here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759932/simple-non-optimal-unionfind-in-ocaml