# Simple non-optimal unionfind in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I wrote a OCaml program for `union find` algorithm. This algorithm I wrote is not optimal and is the simplest version.

I put my OCaml code here because I am not sure whether this code is good enough or not **(despite of the algorithm itself)**, although this code can run without errors.

This is the first time I wrote a complete working thing after I started to learn OCaml, so please help me by reviewing it.

**Useful suggestions will help me improving my OCaml skills. Thanks**

---

```
type union_find = {id_ary : int array; sz_ary : int array};;

let create_union n = {id_ary = Array.init n (fun i -> i); 
                  sz_ary = Array.init n (fun i -> 1)};;

let union u p q = 
  let rec unionfy id_ary i = 
    let vp = id_ary.(p) in
    let vq = id_ary.(q) in
    if i < Array.length id_ary then begin 
      if i != q && id_ary.(i) = vp then id_ary.(i) <- vq;
      unionfy id_ary (i + 1)
    end 
    else print_string "end of union\n"
  in
  unionfy u.id_ary 0;;

let is_connected u p q = u.id_ary.(p) = u.id_ary.(q);;
```

---

First of all,

**Am I creating the data structure of `union` (as in `union find`) correctly?**

**Should I include two arrays inside or is there any better way?**

---

Second,

I am using `array` in this code, but `array` is `mutable` which is not that good for `fp` right?

**Is there a way to avoid using array?**

---

Finally,

Overall, is this piece of code good enough?

**Anything can be improved?**

---

P.S. I am not using OCaml's object oriented bit yet, as I haven't learnt to that part.

Comment: I think http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be better suited for this kind of questions.

Comment: ahh, sorry, didn't know that site.

Comment: There are too many stackexchange sites, no one should be expected to be a casual user of this site and keep track, or have any desire to sign-up for each one (although as trivial as it may be). He has a lot of questions here that belong on this site, I wouldn't worry too much Jackson.

Comment: Thanks @nlucaroni you are right, actually I think stackoverflow is overhelming, too many categories.

Comment: I'm not flaging your question, my comment was just to let you know the existence of this site, so that over time you become a proficient stackoverflow user ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few stylistic points:

Not sure why `unionfy` takes id_ary as a parameter since it keeps it constant throughout

don't use `Array.init` with a constant function. Just use `Array.make`.

`print_string "...\n"` is equivalent to `print_endline "..."`

The following definition can be cleaned up with punning to
`let union u p q =` to: `let union {id_ary; _} p q` so that there are no extraneous references to `u`.

Same punning trick for `let is_connected u p q = u.id_ary.(p) = u.id_ary.(q);;`

This might be a personal choice but I would get rid of:

```
let vp = id_ary.(p) in
let vq = id_ary.(q) in
```

Or at least shove them above the recursive definition so that it's clear they are constant.

EDIT: corrected version

```
let union {id_ary;_} p q = 
    let (vp, vq) = (id_ary.(p), id_ary.(q)) in
    let rec unionfy i = 
        if i < Array.length id_ary then begin 
            if i != q && id_ary.(i) = vp then id_ary.(i) <- vq;
            unionfy (i + 1)
        end else print_endline "end of union"
    in unionfy 0;;
```

Comment: for your punning thing, if I don't ref `u.`, the `id_ary` inside the `u` won't be changed, right? and I need it to be changed as if `multiple union` will be carried out.

Comment: `id_ary` is an array, hence it's mutable. Not sure what you mean. If you're asking if you'll need to change the code, then no you would not because the names are the same.

Comment: what I meant is that if I use `{id_ary;_}` instead of `u.id_ary`, will these two id_ary are exactly the same? I thought OCaml will duplicate the id_ary.

Comment: duplication, will not occur they will be completely identical. I think you are confusing it with functional updates. Arrays are passed by reference by default so only their pointer gets copied. I've also added a cleaned up version of your modified function.

Comment: Ah, ok. how about list? any other types are passed by ref?

Comment: Lists are immutable so they are definitely not copied unnecessarily. Try to dig it up somewhere in the manual I don't want to give you any false information but in general it's also very intuitive since most "simple" types are immutable anyway so it makes very little difference in practice.

Comment: sorry, still confused about list in your comment. let's say if it is `{a_list;_}` in the type `union_find`, then is this `a_list` identical to `u.a_list`?

Comment: if you have a type defined like so: {a_list : some_type} then yes. it's identical. Punning is just syntactic sugar for destructuring records.

Answer (score 5):

Some comments on the code:

- You don't seem to use sz_ary for anything.
- Your code iterates through the whole array for each union operation. This is not correct for the standard (Tarjan) union-find. For a linear number of union operations your code produces a quadratic solution. Wikipedia has the standard algorithm: [Disjoint-set Data Structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

To answer your second question: as far as I know, union-find is one of the algorithms for which there's no known functional (immutable) solution with the same complexity as the best imperative solution. Since an array is simply a map from integers to values, you could always translate any array-based solution into an immutable one using maps. As far as I've been able to determine, this would match the best known solution in asymptotic complexity; i.e., it would add an extra factor of log n. Of course there would also be a constant factor that might be large enough to be a problem.

I've implemented union-find a few times in OCaml, and I've always chosen to do it using mutable data. However, I haven't used arrays. I have a record type for my basic objects, and I use a mutable field in each record to point to its parent object. To do path compression, you modify the parent pointer to point to the current root of the tree.